# How to exactly modify the Local Descriptor table on 64 bits Windows?

Tags: windows, x86-64, 16-bit, mmu

The aim is to enable 16 bits segments for 16 bits addressing like on 64 bits Linux Kernel with the `modify_ldt()` system call.

I was unable to find if Cygwin provides a wrapper and I have only barely an idea that it’s about something like `NtSetLdtEntries` with :

```
typedef struct
{
    ULONG Start;
    ULONG Length;
    LDT_ENTRY LdtEntries[1];
} PROCESS_LDT_INFORMATION, *PPROCESS_LDT_INFORMATION;
```

Please note this is not related to the vm86 mode (which is a different method of doing it used by Microsoft on 32 bits systems). And As stated above, this way is used on Linux for running 16 bits code in protected mode without any emulation. See [`CONFIG_X86_16BIT`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/Kconfig?h=v5.7#n1193) for more informations.

Of course, if it’s not supported by default it’s Ok to modify system files.

Comment: in *x64* windows this is exactly not supported. in *x86* - may be possible

Comment: @RbMm why ? Pleae note I’m not talking about Vm86. The aim is 16 bits addressing without real mode. The way I’m describing works on Linux64 bits.

Comment: simply call `NtSetInformationProcess` with `ProcessLdtInformation` or `ZwSetLdtEntries` in *x64* and you got `STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`. this is fact. on *x86* - may be possible

Comment: *x64* if i not mistake even on cpu level not support segment registers (except *gs*) . on *x86* - possible

Comment: @RbMm Longmode still uses CS to determine the code segment, using the new L bit to switch between the 32 bit and 64 bit sub-modes, and it is still possible to enable the rarely used 16 bit mode using the Sz bit.

Comment: @harold - may be, dont know are this possible on cpu level. however on *x64* windows `ProcessLdtInformation` and `ZwSetLdtEntries` unconditionally return `STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED` - on *x64* windows this is 100% not possible todo. *x86* - this was possible on xp exactly, are possible now - not check

Comment: @RbMm was this possible on 64 bits Windows XP ? Also you should refresh the question for explanations on whether this is already done elsewhere at ᴄᴘᴜ level. Anyway, in that case, I fail to see any reason this should be disabled only on 64 bits.

Comment: that this is not supported by any windows x64 simply fact. on *x86* on xp - this is exactly can be implemented, are latter - dont check. 64bit xp - not exist. exist 64 bit win 2003 :) look also - https://community.osr.com/discussion/99858

Comment: @RbMm Then I’m afraid a French 64 bits version of xp lies on my hard drive (I could download it from Dreamspark before it was ᴇᴏʟ). It was only available as professional edition and limited to Service Pack 2. I no longer use it because they are many compatibility problem : I mean there’s not so much benefits over it’s 32 bits counterpart.

Comment: anyway you can easy check this on some x86 - allocate `PROCESS_LDT_INFORMATION`, set *Start* to first segment number which you want to use (so `8*n` - say for use `0xf` in segment register - set *Start* to 8) *Length* - set to size of `LdtEntries` array (so `sizeof(LDT_ENTRY)*k` where `k` is count of `LdtEntries` you allocate and test result of call `NtSetInformationProcess`

Comment: @user2284570 - this so called *xp x64* really win2003 x64 - if you check it version - you got *5.2* (win2003) but not (*5.1* - xp)

Comment: @RbMm Yes with full xp Userland and stripped from Windows Server features. But it had the same exact look than 32 bits and supportted DirectX (in the lucky case you had a compatible driver of course).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196767/discussion-between-user2284570-and-rbmm).

Comment: @RbMm: Harold is right, this is definitely possible on a CPU level.  A long-mode kernel can run 16-bit user-space.  It's not vm86, it's like 32-bit compat mode (under a 64-bit kernel), but with the default operand-size and address-size being 16-bit.  Just like a 16-bit code descriptor under a 32-bit kernel.  It's not real-mode so you can only set segment bases by indexing into the LDT/GDT with segment selectors.  But yes I'm pretty sure they can be non-zero, like in compat mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes - yes, on cpu mode can (already look for Long bit), but **x64 windows** not support this feature. x86 - support, while *x64* not. modify yoursel gdt/ldt entries, in conflict with operation system - not think will be good result

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, I know you already said x64 Windows doesn't support doing this.  I thought you or other future readers might be interested to know what x86-64 can do vs. what Windows can do.  Oh, I just read more comments and I see the OP hasn't understood that point.  Sorry, didn't mean to pile on and add to those comments that claim it should be possible just because the HW can do it.  Obviously you need OS support as well for it to be *safely* doable.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, i understand this already, about cpu support. not strong on this level, but understand this while looking segment entry description. however *x64* windows by some reason deside not support LDT. api ( `NtSetLdtEntries` and `ProcessLdtInformation`) despite exist, always return status not implemented

Comment: @PeterCordes I perfectly understand that there’s no ᴀᴘɪ *(or rather it’s disabled at run‑time)*. But same as on Linux it’s not because the `modify_ldt()` system call is disabled that Linux doesn’t use the ʟᴅᴛ.

Comment: @user2284570 - if i not mistake - x64 kernel at all never set any LDT, no any supported code for this. so problem not in - no public api - problem - no support at all

Comment: http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?m=201708

Comment: @RbMm Even if it wasn’t handled, it would still need to be saved and restored through the `sldt`and`lldt`opcode.

Answer (score 1):

on *x86*-based windos possible (tested on *xp* and *win 8.1 x86*) set several descriptors in *LDT* table and use this. this can be done via `NtSetInformationProcess` with `ProcessLdtInformation` (undocumented) or, if we need set only 1 or 2 selectors - more easy use undocumented api:

```
EXTERN_C
__declspec(dllimport)
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtSetLdtEntries
(
 __in_opt ULONG Selector1,
 __in SEGMENT_ENTRY LdtEntry1,
 __in_opt ULONG Selector2,
 __in SEGMENT_ENTRY LdtEntry2
 );
```

so we need allocate 1 or more `SEGMENT_ENTRY` (or [`LDT_ENTRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-ldt_entry) - declared in *winnt.h*), allocate memory for segment, and call api. I did not pay much attention for 16 bit code and fill actual descriptors, check only memory fill via *LDT* selector (assigned to *ES*) and then read it via "plain" selector.

```
typedef struct SEGMENT_ENTRY
{
    ULONG   LimitLow    :   16;
    ULONG   BaseLow     :   16;
    ULONG   BaseMid     :    8;
    ULONG   Type        :    4;
    ULONG   IsGegment   :    1;// = 1
    ULONG   DPL         :    2;
    ULONG   P           :    1;// Present 
    ULONG   LimitHi     :    4;
    ULONG   AVL         :    1;// Available For software use
    ULONG   L           :    1;// Long-mode segment 
    ULONG   D           :    1;// Default operand size 
    ULONG   G           :    1;// Granularity 
    ULONG   BaseHi      :    8;
}*PSEGMENT_ENTRY;

typedef struct PROCESS_LDT_INFORMATION
{
    ULONG StartSelector;
    ULONG Length;
    SEGMENT_ENTRY LdtEntries[];
} *PPROCESS_LDT_INFORMATION;

EXTERN_C
__declspec(dllimport)
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtSetLdtEntries
(
 __in_opt ULONG Selector1,
 IN SEGMENT_ENTRY LdtEntry1,
 __in_opt ULONG Selector2,
 IN SEGMENT_ENTRY LdtEntry2
 );

NTSTATUS TestLdt()
{
    PVOID BaseAddress = 0;
    SIZE_T RegionSize = 0x100000;//1mb
    NTSTATUS status = NtAllocateVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &BaseAddress, 0, &RegionSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
#if 1
        SEGMENT_ENTRY LdtEntry = {};
        LdtEntry.LimitLow = 0xffff;
        LdtEntry.BaseLow = ((ULONG_PTR)BaseAddress) & 0xFFFF;
        LdtEntry.BaseMid = ((ULONG_PTR)BaseAddress >> 16) & 0xff;
        LdtEntry.BaseHi = ((ULONG_PTR)BaseAddress >> 24) & 0xff;
        LdtEntry.P = 1;
        LdtEntry.DPL = 3;
        LdtEntry.IsGegment = 1;
        LdtEntry.Type = 2;//ldt

        status = NtSetLdtEntries(8, LdtEntry, 0, LdtEntry);
#else
        const ULONG cb = sizeof(PROCESS_LDT_INFORMATION) + 1 * sizeof(LDT_ENTRY);

        PPROCESS_LDT_INFORMATION LdtInfo = (PPROCESS_LDT_INFORMATION)alloca(cb);

        LdtInfo->Length = 1 * sizeof(LDT_ENTRY);
        LdtInfo->StartSelector = 8;

        SEGMENT_ENTRY* LdtEntry = LdtInfo->LdtEntries;

        LdtEntry->LimitLow = 0xffff;
        LdtEntry->BaseLow = ((ULONG_PTR)BaseAddress) & 0xFFFF;
        LdtEntry->BaseMid = ((ULONG_PTR)BaseAddress >> 16) & 0xff;
        LdtEntry->BaseHi = ((ULONG_PTR)BaseAddress >> 24) & 0xff;
        LdtEntry->L = 0;
        LdtEntry->D = 0;
        LdtEntry->G = 0;
        LdtEntry->AVL = 0;
        LdtEntry->P = 1;
        LdtEntry->DPL = 3;
        LdtEntry->IsGegment = 1;
        LdtEntry->Type = 2;//ldt

        status = NtSetInformationProcess(NtCurrentProcess(), ProcessLdtInformation, LdtInfo, cb);
#endif

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            DbgPrint("%s\n", BaseAddress); // print empty string
#ifdef _X86_
            __asm {
                push edi
                mov ax,0xf
                mov dx,es
                mov es,ax

                mov ecx,32
                mov al,0x33
                xor edi,edi
                rep stosb

                mov es,dx
                pop edi
            }
#endif
            DbgPrint("%s\n", BaseAddress);// print 33333333...
        }

        NtFreeVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &BaseAddress, &RegionSize, MEM_RELEASE);
    }

    return status;
}
```

however [**This is valid only on x86-based windows systems.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-ldt_entry)

if you call this on any *x64* windows you got error `STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`. here windows not support *LDT* at all. and this can not be changed (even by *modify system files.* ?!)

---

more info - [Local Descriptor Table on x64](https://web.archive.org/web/20171028122657/http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=340)

Comment: Local Descriptor Table is a feature of the ᴍᴍᴜ not Windows. So it’s supported. What might not be supported is modifying it from userland.

Comment: @user2284570, not this is not supported by x64 windows, no matter from user or kernel mode. at begin in *GDT* must be selector for *LDT*, but here no such selector, and you can not modify *GDT* yourself

Comment: It needs to be set by Kernel code. It’s supported the same way as ᴘᴀᴇ on 32 bits : third party code including drivers can’t access it.

Comment: @user2284570 - again, this supported by cpu, but no api for this (from user or kernel mode) for this in windows. if you try do this yourself - will be **conflict** with op system. as result nothing happens or will be system crash. say off paging also supported by cpu. but you can not do this in windows

Comment: @user2284570 - but question about *windows*, not *reactOS*. you can not do this in x64 windos not because this is not supported by cpu, but because you conflict here with operation system. and you not win in this conflict. are in *reactos* - i dont know

Comment: @user2284570 - dont know, are you can implement this in reactos. in ms windowsx64 - no

Comment: Ok… It’s not supported in ReactOS whatever the architecture. I noticed ʟᴅᴛ related functions are only present in 32 bits Dlls (see the last edit)… Which brings me to a specific point if you didn’t performed the system call directly (a similar problem exists in Linux) : did you tried this from a 32 bits or 64 bits process ?

Comment: @user2284570 - in x86 windows not exist 64bit processes. this code will be work only in x86 windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196778/discussion-between-user2284570-and-rbmm).